# XPATH remove extra spaces in concatenation of elements

Tags: xpath

In XPATH, I am treating a source XML that looks like below, where I want to concatenate the child elements of each `editor` with a space delimiter to create a full name, and then in turn concatenate the resulting full names with commas:

```
<biblStruct type="book" xml:id="Biller_2011a">
     <monogr>
        <title>Inquisitors and Heretics in Thirteenth-Century Languedoc: Edition and Translation
           of Toulouse Inquisition Depositions, 1273-1282</title>
        <editor>
           <forename>Peter</forename><surname>Biller</surname>
        </editor>
        <editor>
           <forename>Caterina</forename><surname>Bruschi</surname>
        </editor>
        <editor>
           <forename>Shelagh</forename><surname>Sneddon</surname>
        </editor>
        <imprint>
           <pubPlace>
              <settlement>Leiden</settlement>
              <country>NL</country>
           </pubPlace>
           <publisher>Brill</publisher>
           <date type="pub_date">2011</date>
        </imprint>
     </monogr>
  </biblStruct>
```

Currently the XPATH (within XQuery) code looks like this, using XPATH `map` to introduce delimiters:

```
let $bibref := $bib//tei:biblStruct[@xml:id="Biller_2011a"]
return   <editors>{
            (for $auth in $bibref//tei:editor
            return normalize-space(string-join($auth//child::text()," ")))!(if (position() > 1) then ', ' else (), .) 
        }</editors>
```

But this outputs extra space before and after the commas:

```
<editors>Peter Biller ,  Caterina Bruschi ,  Shelagh Sneddon</editors>
```

Rather, I want to output:

```
<editors>Peter Biller, Caterina Bruschi, Shelagh Sneddon</editors>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"where I want to concatenate the child elements of each `editor`" would translate into `$auth/*` and not into `$auth//child::text()`.

Somehow the whole mix of `for return` and `!` and `string-join` looks odd, it seems you can just use `string-join($bibref//tei:editor/string-join(*, ' '), ', ')`.

Comment: Rats, that's a typo, I meant XPATH not XSLT. Updated the question, not that it changes your answer.